# Sum values based on distinct values in another column plus another criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distinct-values

I am trying to find the value of the Sale $ based on the unique Deal #s by location.  I can get a total value for unique Deal #s using

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C11:C23/COUNTIF(B11:B23,B11:B23))
```

but I can't figure out how to break it down by location.  My original formula is shown below along with my expected result by location.  I did try using COUNTIFS but I got a DIV/0 result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sum Unique Distinct Values Based On One Criteria

Try this formula as shown in image below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B6**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$11:$A$23=A6,
MATCH($B$11:$B$23,$B$11:$B$23,0)),
ROW($C$11:$C$23)-ROW($C$11)+1),$C$11:$C$23))
```

Depending on your Excel version you may need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` & then fill down!

Or, If you are using **O365** and presently in **Office Insiders Beta Channel Version**, then you may try the following formulas as well, where **[DROP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34)** Function has been used!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$11:$C$23,A6=$A$11:$A$23)),,2))
```

Or,

```
=LET(r,$A$11:$A$23,s,$A$11:$C$23,SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(s,A6=r)),,2)))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]